# sqlite table columns aren't showing up

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone-8, sqlite-net

I'm using sqlite-net for wp8. I'm trying to insert a row into a table but I get a runtime error saying the column doesn't exist. When I put a breakpoint right before the line and go through the database variable I can see the table and the columns so I'm not sure whats going on. Here is the code:

```
db.BeginTransaction();
                db.Query<Entry>("insert into Entry(desc, date) values (calories = 100, desc = 'food', date = '5/26/13')");
                db.Commit();

public class Entry
{
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Column("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [SQLite.Column("calories")]
    public int calories { get; set; }

    [SQLite.Column("desc")]
    public string desc { get; set; }

    [SQLite.Column("date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mention two columns, then three columns in your SQL query:

```
[...] (desc, date) [...] (calories = 100, desc = 'food', date = '5/26/13')
```

The right query would be:

```
insert into Entry (calories, desc, date) values (100, 'food', '5/26/13')
```

Comment: I fixed it but still same error. Even this still tells me calories doesnt exist: "insert into Entry values (calories = 100, desc = 'food', date = '5/26/13')"

Comment: @AaronKerti: Actually, I've never seen this query style: `INSERT INTO table VALUES (column = value)`. Are you sure this is right?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
db.BeginTransaction();
db.Insert(new Entry() {
                    calories = 100,
                    desc ='food',
                    date = '5/26/13'
            });
db.Commit();
```